# Use a VB variable in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm trying to create a sql statement but I require the use of a VB variable. The problem is, I keep getting an error about too few parameters when I try to just put the variable in. Is there some sort of format I need to use in order to add a VB variable into a SQL statement?

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT StartTime " & _
            "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
            "WHERE TimeID = (SELECT max(TimeID-count) FROM tblLunchTime);")
```

The variable in this situation is 'count'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concatenate the variable like so:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT StartTime " & _
            "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
            "WHERE TimeID = (SELECT max(TimeID-" & count & ") FROM tblLunchTime);")
```

Comment: Relax a bit. VB is typed. How exactly would you inject SQL in an int ?

Comment: This is probably the pattern that is repeated elsewhere, with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Well... using non-parameterized sql like you want to is usually a very bad idea. There are [many articles](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=vb6+parameterized+quer&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vb6+parameterized+query&qscrl=1) on how to parameterize a sql query or use stored procs for VB (6 and .NET).

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate it:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT StartTime " & _
            "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
            "WHERE TimeID = (SELECT max(TimeID-" & count & ") FROM tblLunchTime);")
```